# If $a,b$ are extended real numbers, $f$ is differentiable/$f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, prove uniform continuity.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Suppose $a<b$ are extended real numbers and that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Prove that if $f'$ is bounded on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b).$

Comment: I don't understand why it matters that $a,b$ are extended real numbers.

Comment: It doesn't, really.

Comment: If $f'$ is bounded on $(a,b)$, then for every $s,t$ in the domain, $\frac{|f(s)-f(t)|}{|s-t|}<M$ which implies $|f(s)-f(t)}<M|s-t|$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I'm not sure how/where to apply the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: That's okay - you don't need to use the mean value theorem necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Mean Value Theorem,and bound of $f$, $|f(x)-f(y)|=f'(c)|x-y|$

Comment: What interval do you apply the mean value theorem to?

Comment: How does $[x,y]$ relate to $(a,b)$?

Comment: $a<x<y<b$.........

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS** (sort of)

1. What does it mean that $f'$ is bounded?
2. What does it mean to be uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Hint in addition to @mixedmath, if you know what those definitions mean: use the mean value theorem.